# Generating all 'data dictionary' reports under each 'object' in postgres

Tags: postgresql, report, pgadmin

I have a database with about 50 something tables. I would like to run the report "Data Dictionary" on each table.

Ideally, I would like them all to be in one report, for example, in PGAdminIII, if I right click select "Tables" I will get a report of all the 'objects' and under each one a data dictionary report.

Is there an automatic way of doing this, or an plugin that I can install to postgres? Or is there something analogous to this?

Comment: What do you mean by «Data Dictionary»? Can you provide an example?

Comment: If you're running psql, you might be looking for: `\d *`

Comment: @vyegorov in pgadminiii there is an option to run a report called "data dictionary"

Comment: @casperOne: I think that the pgadmin3 tag was actually correct.

Comment: @wildplasser No longer, see - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130979/140951

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Maybe pgadmin3 would have been a better choice for SEO reasons. (Altering it in the title would be *very* bad, SEO-wise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're referring to the ability to right mouse click on a table in PgAdminIII and select Reports > Data Dictionary report?

I'm not aware of any way to do that from PgAdminIII. You could look into using a different tool such as SchemaSpy. Another option (as alluded to by @kgrittn) is to use psql \d  with the \H flag to generate html output. [My solution](https://github.com/gsiems/DataDict) (since SchemaSpy didn't do what I needed, and I needed the same output for both Postgres and Oracle) was to roll my own using perl, DBD::Pg and Template::Toolkit.

**Update:** Added GitHub link.

Comment: Not what I was looking for initially, but it does what I wanted better anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a fairly simple Postgres data dictionary generator in Python that spans all schemas and tables within a specified database. If it doesn't have exactly what you want it would be fairly easy to modify.

https://github.com/kylejmcintyre/pypostgreports